# Best way to output results from two unidentical database tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have two tables in my database `announcements` and `announcements_external`:

```
+----------+    +----------+
| table1   |    | table2   |
+----------+    +----------+
| id       |    | id       |
| catid    |    | eid      |
| uid      |    | username |
| title    |    | source   |
| text     |    | title    |
| views    |    | section  |
| images   |    | category |
| created  |    | text     |
| modified |    | views    |
| pubdate  |    | images   |
+----------+    | created  |
                | modified |
                +----------+
```

In CodeIgniter framework, I want to merge them, so when I will do a `foreach($results as $item)`, I would output them side by side, ordered by field `created`.

I tried this code but I know it's completly wrong with the merging:

```
public function get_mixed( $limit = NULL, $offset = NULL )
{
    $this->db
        ->select('
            announcements.id,
            announcements.catid,
            announcements.uid,
            section.title AS section,
            categories.title AS category,
            announcements.title,
            announcements.text,
            announcements.views,
            announcements.created,
            announcements.modified,
            announcements.pubdate,
            announcements_external.id as eid,
            announcements_external.eid,
            announcements_external.source,
            announcements_external.username,
            announcements_external.section as esection,
            announcements_external.category as ecategory,
            announcements_external.title as etitle,
        ')
        ->join('categories', 'announcements.catid = categories.id', 'left')
        ->join('categories as section', 'categories.pid = section.id', 'left')
        ->join('announcements_external', 'announcements_external.id = announcements_external.id', 'right')
        ->order_by('created DESC, '.$this->_order_by);

    $query = $this->db->get( $this->_table_name, $limit, $offset )->result();

    return $query;
}
```

By the way, I do `LEFT JOIN` on `categories` table, which works as it should, but I thought it would be better to leave it in this code so you will see it also.

Any solution or maybe guide where I can get more information pls ? Thanks

Comment: With mysql the duplicate column names would be ambiguous and would return the joined/last retrieved if they are not aliased. All left join does is retrieve the joined table data beside the selected table even if no record exists. The end result would be a single iterable array of record sets/rows.

Comment: Why is the given code wrong?  Please post the results of this query, and sample, correct data.  Thanks.

Comment: Bit confused and can use a clarify...are you looking for both tables to have their results outputted on one line, or are you looking for all results in table 1 plus all results in table 2 as seperate rows?

Comment: This join confuses me `->join('announcements_external', 'announcements_external.id = announcements_external.id', 'right')`  you're joining it to itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `Table1` and `Table2` are separated entities so you need to use [UNION ALL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx) instead of JOIN to merge them.

```
(SELECT ..needed columns .. , Table1.created FROM Table1 JOIN categories ... )
UNION All
(SELECT ..needed columns .. , Table2.created FROM Table2 JOIN categories ... )
ORDER BY created ;
```

You will need to use fake columns aliases for nonidentical columns, if necessary.